# selenium c# wait using element name instead of locator (By.Id)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait

Is there any way to pass the IWebElement name as a parameter to Wait instead of the locator (using Id, Xpath, etc.)?

I'm trying to write some code using the Page Object Model, and I have already identified the elements in the POM class as follows:

```
class MyTestPagePom
{
    private IWebDriver driver;

    //Locators
    [FindsBy(How =How.Id, Using = "Questions[0].Answers[0].Id")]
    public IWebElement MyTestElement1 { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a wait method which does the following:

```
public static void HandleWait(IWebDriver driver, By ElementIdentified, int TimeoutInSeconds)
    {
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeoutInSeconds));
        wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(ElementIdentified).Displayed);
    }
```

The method is called like this:

```
HandleWait(driver, By.Id("Questions[0].Answers[0].Id"), 30);
```

Is there a way I can pass the IWebElement name as a parameter to the wait method so that I don't have to pass the Id again while calling the method?

I have searched for solutions and couldn't find any. Apologies if there is a solution that I have missed. I'm new to C# and Selenium , hence any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What happens when you use this :  HandleWait(driver,MyTestElement1 , 30);

Comment: @cruisepandey - Thank you for the response. Unfortunately passing MyTestElement1 did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own custom `ExpectedCondition`. You can see the Selenium source [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/support/UI/ExpectedConditions.cs) and follow that pattern taking in a `IWebElement` as a parameter.

It might be something like

```
public static Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> ElementIsVisible(IWebElement element)
{
    return (driver) =>
    {
        try
        {
            return element.Displayed ? element : null;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```